# how to get GUI on Amazon ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon ec2 instance in which I can login through putty. I want GUI on that instance. Please anyone help me, how can I get GUI on ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

login ec2 instance and execute below commands

```
Sudo apt-get update
Sudo apt-get install lxde
sudo start lxdm
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo passwd ubuntu
```

then open RDC

username -- hostname which you provided in putty

Answer (score 2):

Install VNC and connect using VNC. View the video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeIw4CjwQ44).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an X11 server like MobaXTerm: http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/ ot Xming: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/ (assuming you work on a PC running Windows).